# Find a movie about alien invasion implants devices into human heads for mind control

Tags: story-identification, movie, doctor-who, aliens, mind-control

I'm looking for a  movie where there was an alien put a devices  human heads, and then taking control of their minds. I find some pictures about this movie, but i still don't know the movie's name anyone know?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nope. Nope. I'm looking for the name of the same movie. Definitely 50's, B&W.
The most memorable scene implanted (ha) into this 7 yr-old's putty mind was a close-up of spinning silver drill-bit, getting closer and closer to the back of some poor earthling's head with the purpose of implanting some mind-control device.
It took for-ev-er. They'd break away to something else, then back to the drill. Over and over. Drove me nuts . . . but I loved it.
Come on. Somebody out there must know what movie it is!

Answer (score 9):

The upper picture is of the [Cybermen](http://ru.tardis.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7_2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0.jpg) from Doctor Who, potentially from season 2 given the name of the file.

They certainly seem similar to the design used in the classic serial; Tomb of the Cyberman

[image: Tomb of the Cybermen]

Comment: It looks like it's from [The Moonbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moonbase) from season 4.

Answer (score 8):

As Richard said, those guys in the first shot are Cybermen from the show Doctor Who--the shot with the weird device, and the shot of it being put on someone's head, are from the story "The Moonbase", see the bottom of the page [here](http://geekbat.blogspot.com/2012/01/doctor-who-moonbase.html) for a similar shot (the device is part of the process of converting people into cybermen, similar to the Borg from Star Trek). Two of the four episodes of that serial were destroyed by the BBC, but there's a DVD coming out on Feb. 11 that has the two existing episodes along with animated versions of the lost episodes.